# GStreamer WebRtc failing in chrome sometimes

Tags: webrtc, gstreamer, rtsp

I'm using GStreamer 1.21.1 with GStreamer-Sharp. My application forwards a RTSP stream to chrome browser using WebRTC. The pipeline is:

```
rtspsrc location=rtsp://10.16.14.204:554 ! 
queue max-size-bytes=0 max-size-time=0 ! 
parsebin ! 
rtph264pay aggregate-mode=zero-latency config-interval=-1 timestamp-offset=0 ! 
queue max-size-bytes=0 max-size-time=0 ! 
webrtcbin bundle-policy=max-bundle name=webrtcbin
```

This works most of the time, but I've noticed it occasionally results in the video not playing. In order to test easier, I added a restart button that just stops everything and then restarts it. It takes about 10 restarts before I see the video not play. It's the same code and same rtsp source every time.

I decided to dump the RTCPeerConnection ontrack event data (RTCTrackEvent) to the console and noticed some differences between video that will successfully play and video that won't. The ones I thought were suspicious are:

|  | Video That Plays | Video That Doesn't Play |
| --- | --- | --- |
| MediaStream active property | false | true |
| transceiver direction | stopped | recvonly |
| transceiver currentDirection | stopped | recvonly |
| transceiver mid | null | video0 |
| track muted | false | true |
| currentTarget connectionState | closed | connected |
| currentTarget signalingState | closed | stable |
| receiver transport iceTransport state | closed | connected |
| receiver transport state | closed | connected |

I looked at the local and remote SDPs and I don't see anything out of the ordinary.

Looking at gstreamer logs on the server side along with adding my own logging, I do see that I have stream timeouts (GstRTSPSrcTimeout). However, those seem to happen regardless of whether the video plays or not, so as best I can tell, gstreamer is handling stream timeouts itself. I also have logging to tell me if I get EOS and I don't seem to be getting EOS.

I'm running out of ideas for things to look at. Is there anything in the RTCTrackEvent that could hint at what the problem is?

**Edit 1**

Tested with videotestsrc rather than rtspsrc. Works fine.

Tested with videotestsrc transmitted over rtsp and used my original pipeline with this rtsp url. Works fine.

That appears to narrow it down to there being issues with the original rtsp stream. It's coming from a camera, and I would guess I don't have much of a way to fix whatever is breaking. I think my goal needs to be to detect when there's an issue and then reconnect, but I'm not really sure what a good way of detecting this is.

As mentioned in the original posting, I was concerned about GstRTSPSrcTimeout, but that seemed to happen even when it successfully played. Just to see what happens, I decided to try the following reconnect logic whenever a GstRTSPSrcTimeout occurs:

1. Set pipeline state to Null
2. Set pipeline state to Playing

I was hoping this would make the pipeline recover, but it doesn't. It results in an "Internal data stream error.". At this point, GStreamer puts an error on the pipeline bus. I detect that error and restart everything.

This does seem to fix the issue, but it has the following problems:

1. In cases where GstRTSPSrcTimeout seems to be getting handled internally by GStreamer, there is no need to restart. The restart causes the video to stop, then a loading animation, then the video starts again. Very annoying to have this happen all the time for no reason.
2. In the cases where GstRTSPSrcTimeout has to be handled by me, I'd rather not restart everything. I'd prefer to keep the webrtc connection open and just convince the rtspsrc to reconnect and continue on. Ideally all the user would see is the video stuck at a certain point for a few seconds while this is reconnected.

Comment: My first guess would be an issue with the rtsp source. To rule that out, I would test with a videotestsrc and first make sure the stream is stable with that.

Comment: Also, is it possible that the two columns in your table are swapped? The first says that video is playing when the connection is closed which doesn't make sense.

Comment: Strangely enough, the columns aren't swapped. That's what's so confusing to me. It seems like it should be the opposite. I'll change over to videotestsrc and see if I can reproduce the issue.

Comment: Ok, so videotestsrc over webrtcbin seems to work without issue. I'm also going to try streaming videotestsrc over rtsp so I can test piping that to webrtcbin, but that might take a bit to set up.